# Answer doing the right thing in the wrong language - does that count as an answer?

Tags: discussion, flags, not-an-answer

I recently came across a question tagged [.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net), to which a user had posted an answer explaining exactly how to solve the asker's problem... in Objective-C. I was about to flag the answer as "not an answer", but the reason for that says that it "does not attempt to answer the question". This person clearly made a solid attempt to provide an answer, but for whatever reason, their answer is provably of no use to the asker, as it was written in a language that has no relevance to the scenario.

What's the correct course of action here?

Comment: It _is_ an answer, but it doesn't help the OP. That _could_ make it a low quality answer. Either way, a downvote is probably suitable.

Comment: @Cerbrus It would be low quality, but not *very low quality*.  it shouldn't be *flagged*; it should be downvoted.

Comment: @Servy: edited my comment a bit.

Comment: I think anything in objective-c should be downvoted.  A terrible, ugly language.

Answer (score 3):

When you feel that an answer is not useful, you should be downvoting it.

You should not be flagging an answer because it is wrong, or not an answer that you think is useful.  It's still an answer, just a bad answer.

Comment: That was my original thought, but when the question is "how do I do this in .NET?", posting a non-.NET language actually doesn't answer the question in the slightest.

Comment: @anaximander An *incorrect* answer should be downvoted, not flagged.  I'm not at all disagreeing with you that it's an incorrect answer to the question, but it is *an answer* even if it's not a *correct* answer.

Comment: @anaximander: it may not answer the question, but it is still an attempt at answering it. So, the answer doesn't qualify for the _"Not an answer"_ flag.

Comment: @anaximander also, algorithms and logic can be language independent so it might even still be (a little) useful.

Comment: @ryanyuyu it was a language-feature question regarding accessing methods marked `private`, so there's no algorithm or anything that could be helpful across languages. I can see your point that they did *try* to answer (which is why I came to Meta) but I can't help but feel that when a response in any other language isn't an answer to a question that specifically asks about C# language features.

Comment: @anaximander that's a bit different, yeah.  It would have helped if you provided a link to the answer in your question.  If enough people downvote the answer, the poster might feel like deleting the answer.

Comment: Shog9 has made his opion clear that if you want an apple and you get an orange then it is not an answer: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer

Comment: @NathanOliver I'm pretty sure that that's not the intent of his analogy there.  Wrong bad answers are still answers, and shouldn't be marked as NAA; that's always been *very* clear.

Comment: @Servy What do you think his intention is there?  Would orange be treated as asked X and got answer to Y and not asked X<sub>a</sub> and got X<sub>b</sub>?

Comment: @NathanOliver The intention is someone posting something completely unrelated to the question that clearly isn't even an attempt to answer the question in the author's mind, such as asking a new question, asking a clarifying question of the author, an attempt to reply to another answer, etc, just something that isn't even resembling *an answer*.  If you flag an answer for just being wrong, you'll only get your flag declined.  The way to judge the quality of an answer is voting.

Comment: @Servy Thanks for clearing that up.

Comment: @NathanOliver: If it's an answer, but obviously not an answer to *that* question, NAA is the wrong flag, because it doesn't allow context. Flag it "other", and make the point that it's an answer to an altogether different question concisely but thoroughly there, and thus needs be removed.